# merge data.frame but keep only unique columns?

Tags: r

Let's say I want to merge two data.frames but some of the columns are redundant (the same). How would I merge those data.frames but drop the redundant columns?

```
X1 = data.frame(id = c("a","b","c"), same = c(1,2,3), different1 = c(4,5,6))
X2 = data.frame(id = c("b","c","a"), same = c(2,3,1), different2 = c(7,8,9))


merge(X1,X2, by="id", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)




id same.x different1 same.y different2
1  a      1          4      1          9
2  b      2          5      2          7
3  c      3          6      3          8
```

But how would I get just the different1 and different2 columns?

```
id same different1 different2
1  a    1     4      9
2  b    2     5      7
3  c    3     6      8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could include the column same in your by argument. The default is `by=intersect(names(x), names(y))`. Try `merge(X1, X2)` (it is the same as `merge(X1, X2, by=c("id", "same"))`):

```
 merge(X1,  X2)
 #  id same different1 different2
 #1  a    1          4          9
 #2  b    2          5          7
 #3  c    3          6          8
```

Answer (score 1):

Just subset via indexing in the merge statement.  There are many ways to subset i.e. name, position.  There is even a subset function but the [] notation works well for almost all cases

```
merge(X1[,c("id","same","different1")], X2[,c("id","different2")], by="id", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

As shown in other examples you could put it into the by statement but this will become an issue after you exit the realm of one-to-one merges and enter one-to-many or many-to-many merges.

Comment: and what about the column "same" ?

Comment: You don't want the "same" column at all?  then just remove it from the c() above.

Comment: this does not come from me.